# Android Studio: Github commit warning - Access can be package-private

Tags: java, android, git, github, access-modifiers

[Warning displayed in android studio on GitHub commit request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDpta.png)

I have created earthquake class to hold the relevant data and implemented its getter, setter methods.
I encountered a warning **Warning:(7, 1) Access can be package-private** while I was trying to commit the changes to GitHub.

**My question for this is:**
What is the best practice while defining such classes? Should I declare them public or just leave the access modifier undefined to make it package-private? Or any other suggestions to avoid this warning?

Comment: start with the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in development, you want to follow the principle of least privilege. This means that you only allow the least privilege needed. So unless it *needs* to be public, keep it private/protected. This is a good practice to get into, especially if you start writing SDK's and programs professionally, as public methods can be accessed by anyone, you could inadvertently allow access to methods you didn't intend to.

What you are seeing is just the IDE warning you that you aren't using the variable anywhere else, and could make it private, thus following the principle outlined above. If you want to, you can suppress those warnings, but it's definitely good to limit the access if possible. Consider it a best practice.